# Where is the Chrome settings file?

Tags: google-chrome

Where is the Chrome settings file?

Answer (score 37):

> The user data directory contains profile data such as history, bookmarks, [extensions] and
> cookies, as well as other per-installation local state.
>
> Each [profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) is a
> subdirectory (often `Default`) within the user data directory.
>
> ##### Current Location
>
> To determine the user data directory for a running Chrome instance:
>
> 1. Navigate to `chrome://version`
> 2. Look for the `Profile Path` field.  This gives the path to the profile
>    directory.
> 3. The user data directory is the parent of the profile directory.
>
> Example (Windows):
>
> - [Profile Path] `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
> - [User Data Dir] `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`
>
> ##### Default Location
>
> Generally it varies by
>
> - OS platform,
> - branding (Chrome vs. Chromium, based
>   on `is_chrome_branded` in [GN
>   args](https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration)), and
> - [release channel](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)
>   (stable / beta / dev / canary).
>
> ###### Windows
>
> The default location is in the local app data folder:
>
> - [Chrome] `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`
> - [Chrome Beta] `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome Beta\User Data`
> - [Chrome Canary] `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data`
> - [Chromium] `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Chromium\User Data`
>
> ###### Mac OS X
>
> The default location is in the `Application Support` folder:
>
> - [Chrome] `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`
>
> ###### Linux
>
> The default location is in `~/.config`:
>
> - [Chrome Stable] `~/.config/google-chrome`
>
> The `~/.config` portion of the default location can be overridden by
> `$CHROME_CONFIG_HOME` (since M61) or by `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.
>
> Note that `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` affects all applications conforming to the
> [XDG Base Directory Spec](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html),
> while `$CHROME_CONFIG_HOME` is specific to Chrome and Chromium.

For more details including other operating systems, read the complete official [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

Most settings are profile specific. If you delete the folder, Chrome will simply recreate it the next time you run it.

Comment: And in OS X this is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`

Comment: And in Linux this is located at `~/.config/google-chrome/`

Comment: Do you know how can I change this location in Linux?

Comment: @NoamPeled – I'm guessing you'd have to change the source code and recompile.  Maybe just create a symlink from there to wherever you want it, e.g. `mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/library/google/chrome && cd ~/.config && ln -s ../library/google/chrome google-chrome`

Comment: You can change the location by running Chrome every time using the [--user-data-dir](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#user-data-dir) command-line switch.

Comment: What version of chrome is this applicable from?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the location of your Chrome Profile Settings Path by visiting the `chrome://profile-internals/` URI in Chrome. With a default installation it will just list one profile under 'Person 1' which you click on to show the Profile Path and other details. But if you have more than one profile configured it should list them and you can check the location of the other profiles.