# Where can I find a full list of Chrome's master_preferences?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to programmatically disable password saving for Chrome, and my search has lead me to the `master_preferences` file. However, I can't seem to find any "master" list of every possible configuration item.

I was trying to use this [policy list](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PasswordManager) but it doesn't seem to match the same syntax as the aforementioned file.

Here are a couple links that I found helpful in my search:

- [Configuring Other Preferences](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences) in Chromium's documentation for administrators
- [Where is the Chrome settings file?](https://superuser.com/questions/149032/where-is-the-chrome-settings-file) (Mine seemed to be located at username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences)

Comment: I also want to know this. Their page is really weird. It's something like: Oh and here's a neat file for all you admins out there, and here are some random settings you can change. Where's the documentation?

Comment: Searching for this kind of information,
I find another possibility of Google Chrome configuration using Base Registry, I think this link could be helpful:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202 in fact, this key:
"PasswordManagerEnabled"=dword:00000001
maybe it could desactivate the password manager, no ? Best regards'

Answer (score 8):

The best list of Chrome preferences that I can find is in the Chromium source code:

https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup

Answer (score 4):

[Jay](https://serverfault.com/users/2604/jay-michaud) made a great post on ServerFault: [How can I customize the default settings when deploying Google Chrome for Business?](https://serverfault.com/a/635203/237526).

The relevant section is "**Write a customized master_preferences file**" (important bits quoted below, links removed since not enough rep):

> 1. Review the available distribution settings. These are properties of a `distribution` object, which is contained within the anonymous object in the master_preferences file. The following list of settings was compiled by combining two Chromium source files: master_preferences_constants.h and master_preferences_constants.cc in /trunk/src/chrome/installer/util/.
> 2. Review the available non-distribution settings. These settings go **outside** of the `distribution` object in the JSON. They are applied to the user profile when a user runs Chrome for the first time. The full list of settings is available in the Chromium source files pref_names.h and pref_names.cc in /trunk/src/chrome/common/.