# I copied Chrome's, Opera's and Firefox' folders from my old computer onto my new. Is there a way to retrieve my tabs from them?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, restore

I am using Windows 10, and I copied all the mentioned browsers' installation folders from a computer that used to run on Windows 8.1.

While there doesn't seem to be anything in Opera's folder, there are plenty of files in the other browsers'. I'd like to believe that if I find the correct files, I could copy them to the folders of the current installation in this computer. Is that so?

Comment: You can also try copying stuff from `C:\Users\MonkeyZeus\AppData`. This is where programs tend to store configuration information and stuff.

Comment: In Firefox you need to copy the profile.

Comment: Also, check these out: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3Bs85fkRet4 and http://superuser.com/questions/149032/where-is-the-chrome-settings-file